# Spotify embed Play button on iOS

Tags: embed, spotify

Is there a way to size the Spotify Play Button embed widget for the iOS web browser. When I view it from an iPhone, the player appears as max width (~450px) and max height (~800px) which are much bigger than my set 250x330px. I am embedding this as a widget on a wordpress site. My embed code is below.

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:121423693:playlist:13BiALujfGYzQgNMhuffsJ&theme=white" width="250" height="330" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Is there a something wrong with my code? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this widget on a mobile device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an bug a couple of weeks ago that in Safari on iOS always rendered the play button in its full glory even if the iframe was set to a smaller size, this issue has since been fixed.

I dont think we support smaller iframes than 250x80 (small view) or 250x330 (cover/list view)

Comment: Spotify and I had a few back and forths, but they never followed up after a while. Looks like they did fix it over the summer. 
It looks like the embed Play button's structure is different (haven't checked code) when I just loaded it on my iPhone.